# What are the taxes in India on a transfer of a huge amount like US$10,500,000?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, money-transfer

If someone transferred a huge amount into my SBI bank account, what taxes do I have to pay to the government of India?

Answer (score 5):

Why is someone transferring you 10 million USD?

This is definitely a scam. If it isn't, then depending on why the money is transferred, taxes would be around 3 to 5.5 million dollar.

Comment: Funny how OP said $10.5M. Scams never offer me a round number. Always something like that.

Comment: Mental note for next email to @JoeTaxpayer ... :)